# need help in finding out what this program do-(assembler)

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

i'm new in assembler and i need help to finding out what the program do:

```
  MOV SI, 0x0210
  MOV BX, 0x0220
  MOV CX, 0x5
L1: MOV AL, [SI]
  NOT AL
  INC AL
  MOV [BX], AL
  INC BX
  INC SI
  LOOP L1
  HLT
```

can someone tell me what is the "0x.." in the start of the address?

(all numberd are in HEX).

thank a lot!!

Comment: Well, one thing it *doesn't* do is assemble... `0x` introduces a numeric constant expressed in hexadecimal (i.e. base 16). It sorta looks like an attempt to do 2s complement on a sequence of bytes though...

Comment: @twalberg: It does assemble with nasm.

Comment: @Michael The original, before Jester's edit, did not...

Answer (score 0):

MOV SI, 0x0210 Link to address in SI

MOV BX, 0x0220 Link to address in BX

MOV CX, 0x5 Puts 5 into CX

L1: MOV AL, [SI] (L1 assumed to be a label for jumping too) [SI] points to the value at x210

NOT AL If AL =/= 0 exit loop

INC AL Make AL = 1 if it is 0

MOV [BX], AL Put either 1 or the value of AL into x220

INC BX change pointer to next string (assume they are bytes here)

INC SI ^ same

LOOP L1 go back to L1

HLT ...

Comment: `NOT AL   ; If AL =/= 0 exit loop`  <-- Huh, how does that exit the loop?

Comment: @RobertPounder `HLT` != `NOT`... `NOT` does a bitwise complement on its argument (`AL` in this case). Also, the `INC AL` is not conditional. It simply increments `AL`, regardless of whether it is 0 or not... And `MOV [BX], AL` stores the value of `AL` into the address held in `BX`, not "either 1 or the value of AL"...

Answer (score 0):

As you've noted yourself, the numeric literals are in hexadecimal base. The `0x` is a common *prefix* to express that a number should be interpreted as hexadecimal. Some assemblers use the *suffix* `h` instead (as in `1234h`), and some support both variants.

The `LOOP` instruction decreases `CX` by 1 and jumps to the given address if `CX` != 0. So the loop in this program will run 5 times.

During each iteration, a byte is loaded from a chunk of memory starting at address `0x210`. This value is then negated (`(~x)+1 == -x`), and the result is stored in the chunk of memory starting at address `0x220`. Both the source and destination addresses are incremented so that they point to the next byte in the respective arrays on the next iteration of the loop.